# Notifyicon.BalloonTip not showing properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a notifyIcon that I want to use in WinForms app, to show balloonTips to the user on certain events / issues.

It worked fine, and then I made changes to the application that I cannot see could have influenced the workings of the BalloonTip, but now the balloonTip does not pop up.

The NotifyIcon.Icon appears in the task bar and if you keep looking at the taskbar you briefly see the icon in there (like it flashes), but the actual BalloonTipText and title don't appear

here is the code I am using.

```
private void SetBalloonTip(String BalloonMessage, bool isError)
    {
        AppTips.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
        AppTips.BalloonTipTitle = "Attention";
        AppTips.BalloonTipText = BalloonMessage;
        AppTips.Visible = true;
        if (isError)
        {
            AppTips.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            AppTips.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        }

        AppTips.ShowBalloonTip(300000);
    }
```

whenever I want to show a BalloonTip Message I call the above method.

I have played around with the timeout as I read on other threads it could be a possible issue, but increasing nor decreasing it made any difference. 
I also added Thread.Sleep before calling the SetBalloonTip method, thinking that maybe the method is called too quickly in succession, but that did not make a difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits on the length of `BalloonTipText` and `BalloonTipTitle` on some versions of Windows (but not on others, Windows 10 supports any length for example):

- `NotifyIcon.BalloonTipText` max length of 255 characters
- `NotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle` max length of 63 characters

Make sure your text does not violate these limitations to have it display properly.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that, but checked and I am well withing the length limitations. The BalloonTipTitle is statically set to "Attention" for now and the the BalloonTipText is dymanic, but limited to 30 characters at most.

Comment: I have tested your code in a blank new Forms app and it works as expected "on my machine". Could you try to put the code in a empty app to see if it works there?

Comment: I have also updated my answer - the limit was actually not correct for Windows 10 for example

Comment: You are right. Putting that code in a new little app works fine.
all right, so then its something else... thanks

Comment: Then the problem must be somewhere else in the code :-O . Maybe could you remove and re-add the `NotifyIcon` component from the toolbox? Is it accessed somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks, 
Removed the component and re-added it, and it seems to be happy now.